# How to get excel to auto-outline into groups using Excel Macro?

Tags: excel, vba

So I have a bunch of data in an excel spreadsheet that looks something like this:

| Level | Item No | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | XYZ Project |
| 2 |  | General Items |
| 3 |  | Class A: General Items |
| 4 | 1 | Contractual requirements |
|  | 1.01 | Performance security |
|  | 1.02 | Parent company guarantee |
|  | 1.03 | Advance Payment Bond |
| 4 | 2 | Contractors Insurances |
|  | 2.1 | Contractors Construction |
| 4 | 3 | Specified Requirements |
|  | 3.01 | Establishment |
|  | 3.15 | Removal |
|  | 3.16 | Design |
|  | 3.17 | Operation |
| 2 | 4 | Maintained |
|  | 4.1 | Traffic diversions |
|  | 4.2 | Traffic regulation |
| 3 | 5 | Local access roads within work site areas |
|  | 5.1 | Design, supply and install |
|  | 5.2 | Operation and maintenance |
|  | 5.3 | Handover to other Contractors |
| 1 | 6 | Removal |
|  | 6.1 | Design |
|  | 6.2 | Operation |
| 2 | 7 | Advance Payment Bond |
|  | 7.1 | Contractors Insurances |
|  | 7.2 | Contractors Construction |

I'd like to automatically create groups in the worksheet based on value in column A the result should be like this as show in the picture.

[image]

i tried auto grouping in excel but it doesn't work.

Comment: Would you pls. apply some formatting to your data sample. Something like this [Markdown](https://tabletomarkdown.com/convert-spreadsheet-to-markdown/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```vb
Sub groupHierarchy()

Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ActiveSheet.UsedRange  '---> adjust this to your needs

With rg
    .ClearOutline
    .Parent.Outline.SummaryRow = xlSummaryAbove
End With

Dim arrLevels As Variant
arrLevels = rg.Columns(1)

Dim i As Long, c As Range, targetRow As Long

For i = 2 To rg.Rows.Count  'exclude header
    Set c = rg.Cells(i, 1)
    If LenB(c.Value) > 0 Then
        targetRow = getLastRowForGroup(arrLevels, i)
        If targetRow - i > 1 Then
            c.Offset(1).Resize(targetRow - i - 1).Rows.Group
        End If
    End If
Next

End Sub

Private Function getLastRowForGroup(arrLevels As Variant, rowStart As Long) As Long

Dim lStart As Long: lStart = arrLevels(rowStart, 1)
Dim lCurrent As Long, rowCurrent As Long

Dim i As Long
Do
    i = i + 1
    If LenB(arrLevels(rowStart + i, 1)) > 0 Then
        lCurrent = arrLevels(rowStart + i, 1)
        rowCurrent = rowStart + i
    End If
'stop loop at end of level array or if found level is lower or equal to start level
Loop Until rowStart + i = UBound(arrLevels, 1) Or (lCurrent > 0 And lCurrent <= lStart)

If rowStart + i = UBound(arrLevels, 1) Then 'end of level array
    getLastRowForGroup = UBound(arrLevels, 1) + 1
Else
    getLastRowForGroup = rowCurrent
End If
End Function
```

`groupHierarchy` first retrieves for each row in column 1 the end row for the level (--> `getLastRowForGroup`), then resizes the range to apply the group.

`getLastRowForGroup` iterates over all below levels and returns the row of the first level that is equal or greater than the level to be checked. If level to be checked is the last one, last row is returned.

An array is passed (instead of the range) for performance reason.

Comment: this code works perfectly, until there is case where the level are same on two continues rows next to each other , for example there is level "3" on row 26 and level "3" on row 27 as well, then the above code stop as row 25, it doesn't move forward. i need to run the code skipping the row 26 and run the complete code.

Comment: I updated the code (added `If targetRow - i > 1 Then`) - check if this is the result you are expecting. It is not possible to group a single row!

Comment: this code works this is what i was looking to do.