# Auto Outline using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use a VBA code to apply an outline to an array of data. I have used the answer from this thread, but I receive two errors-

1. The code mistreats the last row.
2. Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range

Thread- How to get excel to auto-outline into groups using Excel Macro
([How to get excel to auto-outline into groups using Excel Macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77945804/how-to-get-excel-to-auto-outline-into-groups-using-excel-macro?newreg=6c2172a8e29642649d9682120523f1ea))

In the data below, Row 20 is grouped under row 17 when in actuality it must be grouped only under Row 2.

Raw data-
[Raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWV6M.png)

Expected output-
[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIamD.png)

Processed Data using code-
[Processed Data using code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlZnU.png)

Run-time error-
[Run-time error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8w9uh.png)

Debug breakpoint-
[Debug breakpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZBpE.png)

What changes do I need to make to the code to handle the last row correctly and resolve the run-time error?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO. 
[Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Please create MD table with online tool [Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Range.Group method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.group?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144141)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Range.End property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.end?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim arrData, iVal As Long, iEnd As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    ' Get the last row#
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    With Range("A1:A" & LastRow)
        ' Clear outline
        .ClearOutline
        .Parent.Outline.SummaryRow = xlSummaryAbove
        ' Load data into an array
        arrData = .Value
    End With
    ' Loop through data
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To LastRow - 1
        If arrData(i, 1) < arrData(i + 1, 1) Then
            iVal = arrData(i, 1)
            iEnd = 0
            ' Locate the end of each group
            For j = i + 2 To LastRow
                If arrData(j, 1) <= iVal Then
                    iEnd = j - 1
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            If iEnd = 0 Then iEnd = LastRow
            If iEnd > i + 1 Then
                ' Group rows
                Range(Cells(i + 1, 1), Cells(iEnd, 1)).Rows.Group
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, this works as intended. Thanks a lot! Also, thanks for providing links to the documentation. I will go through it to understand how you have implemented the logic.